# Lightning console javascript API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, console

I am trying to use Lightning console javascript API based on Summer 17 release notes,
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_lightning_console.htm

```
<force:workspaceAPIAccess aura:id="workspace" />
```

but I am receiving below error when saving my component. 
Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named workspaceAPIAccess found: Source

Component is already added to lightning record page in lightning console app.

my sandbox release version is - Release: Summer '17 Patch 18.2

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Lightning console javascript API is currently a Pilot feature, meaning that the  feature hasn't been made available yet, but is in the final stage of testing.

the title in the release notes indicates it clearly--> Lightning Console JavaScript API (Pilot)

[To participate or test Pilot features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194013&language=en_US&type=1)

> contact your Salesforce.com account rep or Customer Support via
>   help.salesforce.com.
>
> Each nomination is evaluated individually, and orgs that are accepted
>   into the program will be asked to sign a non-GA agreement. Note:
>   Timelines vary due to the amount of review each request is given.

For further details on FAQ you can check:

[Pilot Program FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Pilot-Programs-FAQ&language=en_US&type=1)